# Loop ip range with objective c

Tags: objective-c, ip

I have IP range

```
NSString *startIp = @"192.168.3.15"
NSString *endIp = @"192.168.4.3"
```

and netmask.

```
NSString *netMask = @"255.255.240.0"
```

How can I loop that range with objective c? For example loop and print IP

With in_addr I can turn ip to int

```
struct in_addr startAddr;
inet_aton([startIp UTF8String], &startAddr);

int ipInt = startAddr.s_addr;
```

By incrementing ipInt with 16777216 I will get int number for the next IP. But doing

```
int nextIpInt = ipInt + 16777216
```

is ugly. How can I replace that?

Comment: what are you trying to do with it?  what kind of code are you plugging it into?

Comment: a simple scanner. will try communicate with each IP from the range and find required device. will be a get request like "http://192.168.3.15/api"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using componentsSeparatedByString: to get each part of each ip like this :

```
NSArray *startIpItems = [startIp componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSArray *EndIpItems = [EndIp componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```

Then you can get your int value with

```
[[startIpItems objectAtIndex:0] intValue]
```

and so on for each item and with nested loop, go from your value to 255 each time.

Comment: That is one way but not efficient with a lot of nested loops. There should be some simple solution for that.

Comment: That's 4 loops maximum, one for each ip number, and considering the time your request would take, the looping time would be negligible IMHO.

Comment: I can concentrate on other tasks until I get a good response here or find the way by myself. But answer on my question could be useful for other people in the future

Comment: IPs are int64 types formatted in a special way. You could look into that. But I think you're trying to find a hard solution for a rather simple problem that you could solve in 5 minutes using loops.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is printing the device ip, network ip, netmask and broadcast address and all ip's in network range. It might be helpful.

```
NetworkInformation *network = [[NetworkInformation alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", network);
for(NSString *ip in network.ipsInRange){
    NSLog(@"ip: %@", ip);
}
```

NetworkInformation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NetworkInformation : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *deviceIP;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *netmask;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *broadcast;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *ipsInRange;
- (void)updateData;
- (NSString *)description;
@end
```

NetworkInformation.m

```
#import "NetworkInformation.h"
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>

@implementation NetworkInformation

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self updateData];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)updateData {
    [self updateDataFromWifiNetwork];
    self.address = [self getNetworkAddress];
    self.ipsInRange = [self getIPsInRange];
}

- (void)updateDataFromWifiNetwork {
    self.deviceIP = nil;
    self.netmask = nil;
    self.broadcast = nil;
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0){
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL){
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET){
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]){
                    self.deviceIP = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                    self.netmask = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_netmask)->sin_addr)];
                    self.broadcast = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_dstaddr)->sin_addr)];
                }
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    if(!self.deviceIP || !self.netmask){
        NSLog(@"error in updateDataFromWifiNetwork, device ip: %@ netmask: %@", self.deviceIP, self.netmask);
    }
}

-(NSString*)getNetworkAddress {
    if(!self.deviceIP || !self.netmask){
        return nil;
    }
    unsigned int address = [self convertSymbolicIpToNumeric:self.deviceIP];
    address &= [self convertSymbolicIpToNumeric:self.netmask];
    return [self convertNumericIpToSymbolic:address];
}

-(NSArray*)getIPsInRange {
    unsigned int address = [self convertSymbolicIpToNumeric:self.address];
    unsigned int netmask = [self convertSymbolicIpToNumeric:self.netmask];
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int numberOfBits;
    for (numberOfBits = 0; numberOfBits < 32; numberOfBits++) {
        if ((netmask << numberOfBits) == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    int numberOfIPs = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < (32 - numberOfBits); n++) {
        numberOfIPs = numberOfIPs << 1;
        numberOfIPs = numberOfIPs | 0x01;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < (numberOfIPs) && i < numberOfIPs; i++) {
        unsigned int ourIP = address + i;
        NSString *ip = [self convertNumericIpToSymbolic:ourIP];
        [result addObject:ip];
    }
    return result;
}

-(NSString*)convertNumericIpToSymbolic:(unsigned int)numericIP {
    NSMutableString *sb = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int shift = 24; shift > 0; shift -= 8) {
        [sb appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (numericIP >> shift) & 0xff]];
        [sb appendString:@"."];
    }
    [sb appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (numericIP & 0xff)]];
    return sb;
}

-(unsigned int)convertSymbolicIpToNumeric:(NSString*)symbolicIP {
    NSArray *st = [symbolicIP componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];
    if (st.count != 4){
        NSLog(@"error in convertSymbolicIpToNumeric, splited string count: %lu", st.count);
        return 0;
    }
    int i = 24;
    int ipNumeric = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < st.count; n++) {
        int value = [(NSString*)st[n] intValue];
        if (value != (value & 0xff)) {
            NSLog(@"error in convertSymbolicIpToNumeric, invalid IP address: %@", symbolicIP);
            return 0;
        }
        ipNumeric += value << i;
        i -= 8;
    }
    return ipNumeric;
}

-(NSString*)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"\nip:%@\nnetmask:%@\nnetwork:%@\nbroadcast:%@", self.deviceIP, self.netmask, self.address, self.broadcast];
}

@end
```